# Remembering a variable for next use

Tags: c++, variables, memory, if-statement

I am having a problem with remembering a variable for next use and printing it out. I explain it more so understand what am I trying to do in my program.

I have a person walking on a rectangle of size `a b`. I input starting location `x y` together with persons starting direction (North = y+1, South = y-1, East = x+1, West = x-1 // in my code it is S,J,V,Z). So my input looks like this:

`5 6` // a b
`3 3 S` // x y s(this stands for starting direction - north)

Now, I input number of moves `d` to generate for the person where it should move. 
I enter number 4, and it can generate from 3 letters: D, L, P (Forward, turn left 90 degrees, turn right 90 degrees).

`4` // d
`PLDL` // moves

Now, the person should be walking by those moves. So if the person location and starting direction is `3 3 S`, it should just turn right (my direction is east but same location), then left (direction is north again, same location), then forward (now I move `y+1`, my direction is still north) and last move is turn left(direction west). So mi final location and direction (output) is:

`3 4 Z`

Hope you understand it. If is something unclear, just ask in comment.

I am getting weird output now, unreal numbers. I cant figure out how to put together variables and if conditions to solve it. My code takes first, starting direction and location, but later on when I generate moves, it should change to final output based on the generated string. Sadly, it doesnt work as I expect. Do you have any suggestions? My question is kind of wide but I hope we can solve it together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int n; // pocet uloh
int a; // rozmer obdlznika a
int b; // rozmer obdlznika b
int i;


static const char alpha[] = {'D', 'L', 'P'};
char genRandom()
{

    return alpha[rand() % strlen(alpha)];
}
// end of generator

// funkcia na pohyb

void pohyb (){
    int x[i];
    int y[i];
    string sD = ""; // starting direction
    string mD = ""; // middle direction (stored one for next use)
    string eD = ""; // ending direction to print out in output
    string d = ""; // number of generated directions eg. d=6 ==> PDDLPPD


    for (int i=0; i < d.size(); i++){

            if (sD[i] == 'S'){
                if(d[i] == 'D'){
                    y[i] = (y[i]+1);
                }else if(d[i] == 'L'){
                    mD[i] == 'Z'; 
                }else if(d[i] == 'P'){
                    mD[i] == 'V'; 
                }
            }else if (sD[i] == 'J'){
                if(d[i] == 'D'){    
                    y[i] = (y[i]-1);
                }else if(d[i] == 'L'){
                    mD[i] == 'V'; 
                }else if(d[i] == 'P'){
                    mD[i] == 'Z'; 
                }    
            }else if (sD[i] == 'V'){
                if(d[i] == 'D'){
                    x[i] = (x[i]+1);
                }else if(d[i] == 'L'){
                    mD[i] == 'S'; 
                }else if(d[i] == 'P'){
                    mD[i] == 'J'; 
                }    
            }else if (sD[i] == 'Z'){
                if(d[i] == 'D'){
                    x[i] = (x[i]-1);
                }else if(d[i] == 'L'){
                    mD[i] == 'J'; 
                }else if(d[i] == 'P'){
                    mD[i] == 'S'; 
                }    
            } // koniec if podmienky
    eD = mD[i];
    } // koniec for loopu
    // vystup
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {

        if(!((x[i]>=0)&&(x[i]<=a) & (y[i]>=0)&&(y[i]<=b))){
            cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << eD[i] << ' ' << "SPADOL" << endl;
        }else{
            cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << eD[i] << endl;
        }

    } 

} // koniec funkcie pohyb



int main() {

    cin >> n;
    vector<int> x(n); // x position
    vector<int> y(n); // y position
    vector<int> d(n); // zombie directions generation ex. DPLDDP 
    vector<string> sD(n); // starting direction
    vector<string> eD(n); // ending direction

    while(!((n >= 1)&&(n <=15000)))
    {
        cout << "max 15000" << flush;
        cin >> n;
    }


    cin >> a >> b;

    while(!((a >= 1)&&(a <=100) & (b >= 1)&&(b <= 100)&&(a!=b)))
    {
        cout << "chyba max 100 alebo a!=b" << endl;
        cin >> a >> b;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {    
        cout << "Uloha " << i+1 << ":" << endl;
        cin >> x[i];
        cin >> y[i];
        cin >> sD[i];

        while(!((x[i]>=0)&&(x[i]<=a))) {
            cout << "Try Again x: " << flush;
            cin >> x[i];}
            while(!((y[i]>=0)&&(y[i]<=b))) {
                cout << "Try Again y: " << flush;
                cin >> y[i];}

                cin >> d[i];
                while(!((d[i]>=1)&& (d[i]<=200))) {
                    cout << "Try Again d: " << flush;
                    cin >> d[i];}


                    for (int counter=0; counter<d[i]; counter++)
                    {
                        cout << genRandom();
                    }
                    cout << endl;

    }    // koniec for

    pohyb();
system("pause");

}
```

Sample input:

```
3
3 5 
2 2 S 
8
DPLDLPDD
2 4 Z
7
PDDPDPD
2 1 J
8
PPDLDDDD
```

and output

```
2 5 S SPADOL // spadol means his location is out of the rectangle
3 4 J
0 2 Z SPADOL
```

Comment: You should use `switch()` instead of `if` and this `y[I] = (y[I]+1)` is the same as `y[I] ++` or `y += 1` and variables sD, mD, eD should be `char` and not `string` if you want to remember only one symbol

Comment: You should provide a sample input, its expected and actual outputs.

Comment: @Quest okay, and how can I change the rest of the code because Im getting `[Error] invalid types `char[int]' for array subscript` for `== S`, etc... when I change sD, mD, eD to char

Comment: @febeks That's a minor issue you can fix after you get your code working.  DID YOU READ the item 2 of my answer?

Comment: @febeks Added an edit to my answer that explains how to pass a variable rather than it's value to a function.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than fix your code, I'm going to give you a number of explanations that should help you understand and fix it yourself.

Firstly, let me adjust your understanding of what a variable is. In a programming language, there are values that need to be stored. Once we store a value, we will need to be able to retrieve it again and so we will need a way to describe where it was stored.

```
int i = 5;
```

This tells the compiler to create an instance of the `int` value type, to assign it the value of 5, and to call it `i`.

However, C++ is a scoped language. That means that there is a limitation on how visible any given name is.

```
int x() {
    int i;
}

int y() {
    i = 5; // ERROR: I not declared in this scope.
}
```

In the above code, we declared `i` in one scope - the function body of x - but then tried to use it in another.

C++ scopes are generally distinguished by '{ ... }', for example the following is valid:

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 0; // globally visible 'i'.

void f() { std::cout << "from f i = " << i << '\n'; }

int main() { // <-- function body scope
    int i = 1;
    { // inner scope
        int i = 2; // new variable, called 'i', but only inside this scope.
        { // <-- another inner scope
            i = 3;
            f();
        }
    } // scope ended, the second 'i' has no gone away.
    std::cout << "from end of main i = " << i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The above program prints "0" and then "1".

C++ allows us to do something call "shadowing" - we can use the same name for **different** variables in *different* scopes.

Scope also affects the "lifetime" of variables (see http://ideone.com/fXPlB7), but I'm not going to cover that.

Let me demonstrate more clearly the implications - that the variables have a similar name but are NOT the same variable:

```
int i = 5;

void f(float i)
{
    std::cout << "in f, i is " << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    char i[] = "Hello";

    f(3.141);

    std::cout << "in main, i is " << i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

What does this program print?

Make sure you understand this: *i* is not changing, but rather *which variable `i` refers to in a given scope*.

In your function `pohyb`, you have the following two lines of code:

```
string d = ""; // number of generated directions eg. d=6 ==> PDDLPPD

for (int i=0; i < d.size(); i++){
```

This declares a new variable and within this scope causes the name `d` to refer to it. `d` is an empty string.

The next line iterates over all the values in `d`. How many values are in the empty string? 0. So, the for loop line says this:

```
int i = 0;
is i < 0?
```

0 is not < 0, so the loop is never executed.

Your next problem is the difference in C++ between a character-string (C-string) and a character-array.

C++ is based on C, which did not have a 1st-class definition of a "string". Instead, C has a convention that says: "a string is an array of 0 or more chars followed by a zero-value char".

```
char empty[1] = { 0 }; // valid, empty string. it has 1 element, the 'nul'.
char a[] = { 'a', 0 }; // represents "a", size is 2 chars, 'a' and '\0'
char hello[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 }; // size 6, 5 letters and a nul
char Hello[] = "hello"; // short-cut for writing the above
char ten[] = { '1', '0', 0 }; // '0' and 0 are not the same
char hundred[] = { '1', '0', '\0' }; // '\0' == 0
char ouch[4] = "ouch"; // ERROR: the string is actually 5 chars.
```

All of the C functions that deal with "strings" (not to be confused with std::strings), operate on this principle -- the only way to tell the length is to count characters until you reach a value of zero.

For your purposes, you *actually* want an array of characters, but that does not automatically make them a string.

Your code uses `strlen` to find the number of elements in a char array - this is incorrect, and potentially dangerous for your application. The bytes immediately following the 3 valid elements of `alpha` could be anything, so `strlen` might return 3 or it might return very large values.

What you actually want is the C keyword `sizeof`.

`sizeof(X)` is a compile-time determination of the size of a thing. When X is a fully qualified array, it returns the size in bytes of X. Be aware that this means you can only use it on an array in the global or local scope: [when you pass arrays to functions they are passed by pointer](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html).

```
#include <iostream>

char hello[] = "hello"; // has size 6: 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0

void f(char x[])
{
    std::cout << "f(x), sizeof x = " << sizeof(x) << '\n';
}

void g()
{
    char x[] = "world";
    std::cout << "g() sizeof x = " << sizeof(x) << '\n';
}

void h()
{
    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    std::cout << "h() sizeof x = " << sizeof(x) << ", but sizeof(x[0]) = " << sizeof(x[0]) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main() sizeof hello = " << sizeof(hello) << '\n';
    f();
    g();
    h();
    return 0;
}
```

What do you expect the output to be? Paste to [ideone](http://ideone.com/) if you want to find out.

For your code, the use of a char array looks correct, so you want to use `sizeof` to determine how many chars are in the array. Remember that `sizeof` returns the size in bytes, the formally *correct* way to write this would be:

```
size_t index = size_t(rand()) % (sizeof(alpha) / sizeof(*alpha))];
return alpha[index];
```

This will take the total size of alpha and divide it by the size of *what type alpha points to/contains* (a char). These values are known at compile time so the compiler will do this calculation and emit code equivalent to:

```
return alpha[rand() % (3 / 1)];
```

or just

```
return alpha[rand() % 3];
```

There are 3 elements in alpha, but C/C++ arrays are 0 indexed, so the modulo will provide us a value [0,3) i.e. 0, 1 or 2.

Lastly, you were concerned about working with if statements. For complex logic, sometimes the best thing to do is to write them out and run thru them by hand. You may want to familiarize yourself with the `switch` keyword which takes a variable and matches it against potential values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    while (std::cin.good()) {
        std::cout << "Direction? (n/s/e/w/q): ";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        // if input is empty, input[0] would be undefined behavior.
        if (input.empty())
            continue;

        switch (input[0]) // check the first character only
        {
            // input[0] is of type char, so we can express our values
            // a character literals. we could also write the ascii values,
            // e.g. for 'n' we could put "case 110:"
            case 'n':
                std::cout << "You have entered a dark room.\n";
                break; // escape the switch, not the loop.

            case 'e':
            case 's': // no break, 'e' falls thru
            case 'w': // still no break, 'e' and 's' fall thru
                std::cout << "You can't go that way.\n";
                break;

            case 'q':
                std::cout << "bye!\n";
                return 0;
                break;

            default:
                std::cout << "I asked you to type n, s, e, w or q, but you typed " << input << ".\n";
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/s4xana

---- EDIT ----

On "remembering" values between scopes. Within a function body and nested scopes, this happens automatically:

```
int main() {
    int i = 1;
    { // inner scope
         std::cout << "inner scope\n";
         { // another inner scope
             if (i == 1) {
                 // this is a scope
                 std::cout << "i = " << i << '\n'; // prints 1
             }
         }
    }
}
```

But between functions and modules, you need to make them function arguments.

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int i, int j, int k) {
    std::cout << "f() i = " << i << ", j = " << j << ", k = " << k << '\n';
    i = 10;
    j = 100;
    k = 300;
}

int main() {
    int j = 42;
    f(j, j, j);
    std::cout << "in main: j = " << j << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

What does this print? Remember: variables are locally scoped. Just because they have the same name as another variable in a different scope does not make them connected.

Think of the following code like this, WARNING: PSUEDO CODE:

```
define f - takes int as f::i, int as f::j, int as f::k
    "f() i = ", f::i, ", j = ", f::j, ", k = ", f::k, '\n';
    f::i = 10;
    f::j = 100;
    f::k = 300;
end f

define main
    declare main::j as int
    let main::j be 42
    call f with f::i = 42, f::j = 42 f::k = 42
    "in main: j = " << main::j << '\n';
end main
```

Now it perhaps makes more sense - even tho we changed `j` in `f` it was not the same `j` as we are seeing in main.

How to overcome this:

C++ provides two methods. The old, 'c' method is to pass the address of a variable, called passing it by pointer. Pointers can get hairy and often confuse new programmers, so instead I'm going to show you the C++ mechanism: reference.

As you just saw above, when you call a function with an argument, C++ creates a new locally-scoped variable and *copies* the value of the input variable into it:

```
void f(int n)
{
    n += 2;
}

f(5);
```

Here we see that '5' is *not* a variable, but a hard coded value. There is no way that 'f' could work otherwise - throughout the program '5' would have become 7.

When we want to say "call f and operate on my LOCAL variable" we use a reference.

```
void f(int& n)
{
    n += 2;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 23;
    f(x);
    // x is now 25
}
```

It's tempting to think that a reference is somehow just an alias, but that's not how they are implemented. A reference is a clever way of passing the location in memory of an existing variable, but not clever enough to be aware of that variable going away or being relocated in memory.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(5);
int& first = v[0]; // reference to the first element of v at the moment,.
std::cout << "first = " << first << '\n'; // prints 5.
v.reserve(2000); // causes 'v' to relocate in memory
v[0] = 25;
std::cout << "first = " << first << '\n'; // may crash or print 5, but not 25.
```

The other thing to remember about references is that once they are connected to something, you cannot change the connection:

```
int a = 5, b = 6;
int& r = a;
std::cout << r;
r = b;
std::cout << r;
std::cout << a;
```

This prints: 566, not 565 because `int& r = a` made `r` a reference to `a`. When we said `r = b`, because `r` is now a *reference to `a`* we effectively said `a = b`.

---- EDIT 2 ----

C and C++ have a modifier keyword, `const` which is a contract that says you promise not to modify a thing. If you want to write a function that accepts a complex object by reference (to avoid copying strings, etc, which is expensive), but you don't want to change it, you can use the const modifier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void writeln(const std::string& str)
{
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::string greeting = "hello";
    writeln(greeting);
}
```

Also, a note on '&'. It doesn't matter to the compiler whether you write `string& str` or `string &str`, they mean the same thing. Whether `&` means 'reference' or 'address of' (for pointers) or 'and' (for logic) depends on the context.

Comment: @kfstone Wow... how long you was writing this? +1 ... when you do this: `int a = 5; int *pA = a;` and then `a = 7;` pA == 7 or not?

Comment: @Quest if you write `int a = 5; int *pa = &a; a = 7; int b = *pa;` then dereferencing pa (`*pa`) would give 7 instead of 5, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Note: these are written before you post your sample input and output.

1. When you define `alpha` as

   ```
   static const char alpha[] = {'D', 'L', 'P'};
   ```

   it's really a char array of three elements.  However `strlen()` is a function to count the number of characters before the 1st `\0` (NUL) character encountered.  So `strlen()` in your `genRandom()` will not work as you expect (I guess it returns a random large number.)  You should define `alpha` as

   ```
   static const char alpha[] = "DLP";
   ```

   to add an implicit 4th element `\0` to `alpha`.
2. In your `pohyb()` you define `string` varibales `sD`, `mD` and `d` with empty initial values.  They have no relationship with `vector<int> d` and `vector<string> sD, mD` in your `main()`.  So all your `i < d.size()`, `sD[i] == 'S'`, `d[i] == 'D'`... will not work as you expect.  You should pass `sD`, `mD` and `d` in your `main()` to `pohyb()` as arguments.
   **Update:** OK I'll be more specific.  Because `string d` in `pohyb()` is unrelated to `vector<int> d` in `main()` and remains empty throughout `pohyb()`, `for (int i=0; i < d.size(); i++)` will not run even once.  Because `int x[i], y[i]` in `pohyb()` are unrelated to `vector<int> x, y` in `main()` and contain uninitialized (= random) `i` elements (here `i` happens to be equal to `n` when `pohyb()` is invoked) you see weird ("SPADOL") outputs.  Please learn how to pass parameters to a function in C++ first.  You will get nowhere until you learn it.

I haven't checked if these two are all you need.  They are just obvious mistakes I found so far.  You might need a fundamental rework on your program structure.

Comment: `you should define alpha as static const char alpha[]` - **no**. His first instinct, to make it just an array of 3 characters, was correct. What he should do is use sizeof: `alpha[rand() % (sizeof(alpha) / sizeof(alpha[0]))]`. `sizeof(alpha)` will return the size in bytes of alpha, `sizeof(alpha[0])` will return the size of the elements in alpha, dividing size-in-bytes into number-of-elements. Since alpha is an array of chars, that will give him the number of chars in the array. Since arrays are 0 based, this will give him the correct randomisation he's looking for.

Comment: @kfsone Well, it's just that there are (at least) two ways to fix his `genRandom()`;  one is what you proposed and another is what I proposed.  Neither of them should be considered wrong.  As a side note, it is worth noting that `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: random generation is not my problem, I have a problem with changing vaues x y s...as I described

Comment: @nodakai They're NOT a c-string, they are a character array, so using string tools on them is incorrect as is adding a nul byte and making them string-like.

Comment: @febeks Random generation IS one of your problems. Using `strlen(alpha)` on your 3-byte character array is not going to return sensible values. If `rand() % strlen(alpha)` evaluates to `9827341`, what will `alpha[9827341]` evaluate to?